# Download google docs using Authorisation token

Tags: ios5, google-docs

I have used the https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin url to access the google docs in these i can successfully login and am getting the Authorisation token .Can any one please help me to download all the documents using these authorisation token in Google docs.

Thanks